# Google cloud is caching my static files

Tags: static, memcached

Google cloud seems to be caching my static files hence my changes in CSS are not being reflected. How do I go about this.

Note: it's just a simple static site

Comment: have you clear you browser cache first ?

Comment: Wow, thanks it worked.I didn't realize the issue was from the browser itself

Comment: I already gave it but you can still give it. I'll accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its browser issue so please clear your cache 
to clear the browser cache in google chorme browser to follow this steps :

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Click More tools and then Clear browsing data.
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All
   time.
5. Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files,"
   check the boxes
6. Click Clear data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from the browser. I cleared the cache and everything works fine

Comment: This is my solution but why you have answer that ? pleaes delete you answer i will post that as a answer

Comment: Sure. I'm sorry about that. I'll delete it now

Comment: Seems I can't delete it from the app. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: no problem just uovote and accept my answer ok . thanks